# How to set up window size for desktop Windows app?

Tags: flutter

How to set up windows size for Windows desktop Flutter app?
It seems by default the app trying to make window size in accordance with dectop size, but on the left side it doesn't fit desktop border.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the size & position in the windows/runner/main.cpp file

Position on screen :

```
  Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10);
```

Size on screen :

```
  Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
```

The issue you're having is with the origin on 10,10.